# What is the best strategy to convert silverlight application to html?

Tags: html, .net, silverlight, migration

We have an application that is heavily used. In this application we have business logic in our viewmodels and in the service layer

Now we need to migrate the app to html because of performance issues, plus considering that Microsoft throw out the support for this technology.

We can't just stop the application for several months to finish it's migration. Our clients needs to use it. My first approach will be to migrate all the business logic to the services, making the app a thin client, so we can later use the services for ayax calls in a new ui, made with html

Do you have any experience with this migrations? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 2):

We are currently doing one of these projects

what I would recommend is following

1. Have all business logic that aren't UI specific or silverlight specific in its own Business Libraries.
2. Put a service layer WCF or WebAPI (REST) on top of the Business logic so all the business logic can be accessed via different technologies
3. Use AngularJS or ASP.NET MVC + AngularJS combination so you can keep MV* pattern going and most probably use most of your ViewModel logic with bit change while giving some what similar experience to customers that are used to silverlight UI

1 and 2 was very important in our project because it gave that clean separation and flexibility to expand to any client machine without changing minimum code. Ex: later if we decided to make an Android app you just have to transfer only viewmodel logic without touching your business logic or services.